# Docker .NET Core Connecting to VPN Postgres

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I am Trying to connect .NET Core Application Container to a database across VPN.
Any Instructions how to do that?

Comment: Can you elaborate more your question? You are asking how can your container can establish a VPN connection then connect to the database? If not, assuming you got VPN access, setting-up your connection string should do it.

Comment: @Mihaimyh I have a VPN access using Cisco AnyConnect, but i think i have to use network bridge to connect to that VPN and i have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

you can do that, Using TOR for built vpn connection in any programming and its completely free and unlimited.

and i found some coding reference on google

So, please follow this link its do help for you [reference coding link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1072864/Tor-NET-A-managed-Tor-network-library)